# pyzbar not working after uninstalling anaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda, pyinstaller

I was working on a script which reads qrcodes and writes the data to a file, it was working absolutely fine so I decided to convert the script to an exe file using pyinstaller but after successfully
converting the script to executable if I tried to run it,It would throw an error "**failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres**",I thought there might a problem with anaconda so I decided to uninstall it and instead install the latest version of python but soon as I installed python including the required modules  my script stopped working it still opens the camera but when I show it the qr code to it, it doesn't do anything, can anyone please help me? In the script below initially the **"success**" variable is set to 
**None** so that whenever the pyzbar successfully reads the qr it returns the data converted to a string to the ***success*** variable so that we can later write it to a file "***data.txt***"

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN

success = None

focus = 20

while True:
    _, frame =cap.read()


    frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)

    cap.set(28,focus)

    qr = pyzbar.decode(frame)

    try:
        success = str(qr[0].data)

        cv2.putText(frame,str(qr[0].data),(50,50),font,2,(255,0,0),3)

        break
    except IndexError as e:

        pass


    cv2.line(frame,(0,240),(640,240),(0,0,255),1)
    cv2.line(frame,(320,61),(320,419),(0,0,255),2)


    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
try:
    with open("data.txt",mode = 'w') as f:
        f.write(success[1:])
except TypeError:
    pass
```

Comment: Are you using the same packages as you were with Conda? What made you think Conda was the issue in the first place? Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: @AMC Yes I tried reinstalling conda but regardless of it executable would still always throw the same error, and about the packages, I didn't install exactly the same packages as conda but only the one's that were required in the project